# Why is WeatherData not available for some U.S. states?

Tags: curated-data

I would like to get historical monthly precipitation for all U.S. states.

However, `WeatherData` fails for some U.S. states and works for others.

Why is this?

Is there another way to get this data?

Screenshot of the problem and code below:

[image]

```
WeatherData[
 "Iowa",
 "TotalPrecipitation",
 {
  {1988, 06, 01},
  {1989, 06, 30},
  "Month"
  }
 ]

WeatherData[
 "Nebraska",
 "TotalPrecipitation",
 {
  {1988, 06, 01},
  {1989, 06, 30},
  "Month"
  }
 ]
```

When I try to list of entities as suggested by the error message using `WeatherData[]` I see that neither state is in the entity list:

```
MemberQ[wd, "Iowa"] (* False *)
MemberQ[wd, "Nebraska"] (* False *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Represent the states by the appropriate [`Entity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html)

```
states = EntityList[
   EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "AllUSStatesPlusDC"]];

data = {#, 
     WeatherData[#, 
      "TotalPrecipitation", {{1988, 06, 01}, {1989, 06, 30}, "Month"}]} & /@ 
   states;
```

[image]

```
Length@states

(* 51 *)

Count[data, TimeSeries, {0, Infinity}]

(* 51 *)

Select[data, #[[1]] === 
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Nebraska", "UnitedStates"}] &]
```

[image]

Or use a city

```
WeatherData["Omaha", "TotalPrecipitation", {{1988, 06, 01}, {1989, 06,
    30}, "Month"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. From the message in your ouput I note in the docs that "The location can also be given as {lat,long}, or a city specification is given of the type used in CityData, in which case WeatherData[loc,\[Ellipsis]] gives results for the nearest high-reliability weather station." Does this imply that instead of state `TotalPrecipitaion` we are just getting the data from one weather station?

Comment: I would infer that but I don’t know.